# How to define combine loss function in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

My model arch is
[image]

I have two outputs, I want to train a model based on two outputs such as mse, and cross-entropy. At first, I used two keras loss

```
model1.compile(loss=['mse','sparse_categorical_crossentropy'], metrics = ['mse','accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
```

it's working fine, the problem is the cross entropy loss is very unstable, sometimes gives accuracy 74% in the next epoch shows 32%. I'm confused why is?

Now if define customer loss.

```
def my_custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   mse = mean_squared_error(y_true[0], y_pred[0])

   crossentropy = binary_crossentropy(y_true[1], y_pred[1])
   return mse + crossentropy
```

But it's not working, it showed a negative loss in total loss.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to judge the issues depending on the information given. A reason might be a too small batch size or a too high learning rate, making the training unstable. I also wonder, that you use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` in the top example and `binary_crossentropy` in the lower one. How many classes do you actually have?